# rollback issue during integration testing on historical type table

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

i'm running an integration testing for my service using below annotations. in my service class i have 3 repositories that calls delete methods. however 1 of my repository is a historical table which contains 0..n records. After running the test the historical table does not rollback. Is there a special spring-data-jpa method for deleting historical type table?

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class MyTestClass {
  @Test
  public void testMethod() {    
       service.cleanup();
  }
}
```

```java
public class MyService(){
  @Transactional
  public void cleanup(long id){
    repository1.delete(id); 
    repository2.delete(id);
    repository3.delete(id); //history table
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to rollback the transaction? Or you want to commit it? Question seems like you want to delete historical table data.

Comment: Is the repository method that deletes the historical data configured with `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)`? Or does it programmatically manage transactions?

Comment: @VijendraKulhade, I was expecting a rollback, according to documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing-tx after running the test all my transaction will automatically rolled back.

Comment: my repository methods/class does not have any @Transaction annotation. my service methods/classes have them.